# Help me on CORS Access Control Allow Origin

Tags: php, htaccess

I have one domain having mywebsite.com and there would be multiple subdomains like subdomain.mywebsite.com , subdomain1.mywebsite.com , subdomain2.mywebsite.com and so on.

In htaccess file I have added

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin  "http://subdomain.mywebsite.com"  
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin  "http://subdomain1.mywebsite.com"
   .... and so on it will be there.
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>
```

When I add this code to htaccess then I don't get any CORS error but now I don't want any errors for all the subdomains as above. I need dynamic code for multiple subdomain. So i don't need to add these lines often and often.

Answer (score 0):

> SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*.example.com)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
>
> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN}e"
>   env=ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN

Comment: Do i need to insert subdomain name for ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN ?

Comment: Please provide some information about that so that it can helpful for future reference

Comment: No need to insert subdomain name for ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN, try it in your development environment first.